# Electrostatic in an Arcade Machine (Arduino)

Tags: arduino, electrostatic

I set up an arcade machine, which consists of an Arduino, a coin validator, a 12 V adapter, and a PC. It works as expected, when I insert a coin, a signal is captured via Arduino. The output normally stays at 0 V, goes to 5 V when a coin is inserted for a brief period.

**The problem is** time to time, when I touch the metal part of the coin validator (see picture), it mistakenly sends a signal as if a coin is inserted.

When the metal part of the coin validator is removed, this problem stops. 
We use grounded AC socket and connected it to the ground of adapter and Arduino, but it did not solve the problem.

How can I solve this problem, or what might be the source of the problem?
I talked with the seller, and he said our circuit is correct, but he never heard such a problem. It is also possible that wooden part (MDF) plays a part here.

[image]

Schematic is below (1K resistor)
[image]

**EDIT**:
I connected only Arduino to PC directly with USB cable, and removed the coin validator, resitor and adapter from the system. When I touch the interrupt pin with a jumper cable, it reads a signal.

Comment: no schematic ?.

Comment: @MITURAJ I added it.

Comment: That's just the block diagram. What's the method used to in the circuit to detect that coin is inserted ? And what's the resistor doing there ?

Comment: Ah sorry, the coin validator does not provide the datasheet, it is a cheap AliExpress coin validator, there is no circuit element we added other than that resistor. The coin validator sends a 100 ms square pulse when a coin is inserted on the data cable. The signal is received via a interrupt pin. The tutorials in the Internet with the same coin device, use that resistor.

Comment: Is the metal chassis of the coin mechanism grounded?

Comment: @Trevor_G yes. There are three holes in the plug, and we connected it to the ground (not neutral nor hot).

Comment: @EmmetB did you verify the pins actually connect to the metal though. The chassis ground may not go through the plug.

Comment: If you mean whether the chassis and earth pin is connected, yes we verified that. If you mean if the earth pin in the plug is really connected to earth, that the voltage between earth and neutral should be around 0, we did not check it. Because we are not confident playing with electricity, and safety issues. I am not sure what will happen to my multimeter and whether it is safe if i connect between hot and ground. Because there is no sign which hole is hot and which hole is neutral, we only know which one is earth.

Comment: ESD induced ground shift can be eliminated by understanding ground physical path which is unclear with your lack of details

Comment: I edited my post, I removed all the parts (validator, adaptor and resistor). I connect only Arduino to PC via usb, and when I touch the interrupt pin with a jumper cable, Arduino thinks this is a valid signal. Interrupt is set on rising signals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 10 K pull-up or pull-down resistors and capacitors on input pins.

For 5 V logic, 10 nF to 100 nF works fine.

Comment: an RC circuit, or they should be parallell? Value for C?

Comment: For a 5v logic, 10nf to 100nf works fine

Comment: Please edit information into your answer, don't add it on comments. Thanks.